# Convert a string into a formula in R

Tags: r

I have several formulas in string form, read from files, like this: `"0.657 + 0.343*age - 1.239 * cholesterol"` and I would like to convert each of these into a formula object to run on a data frame (ie. `my.formula <- 0.657 + 0.343*age - 1.239 * cholesterol`) . How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: Possibly useful [`formula`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `eval` and `parse`

example:

```
> cholesterol <- 2  # set some values for cholesterol and age
> age <- 3
> eval(parse(text="0.657 + 0.343*age - 1.239 * cholesterol"))
[1] -0.792
```